# Access to a php WebService from a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, webservice-client

i'm facing a big problem,

I've just made a personnal extension for chrome and i actually need to make it access to a webservice made in php to retrieve some information.

The problem is that i have absolutely NO IDEA how to do that...

Hope's somebody can help me.

Comment: First you have to tell us more about the web service you need to connect to. Your own? A third parties? What type of web service? Is there documentation, etc?

Comment: Not a lot of informations, apparently it use Soap. It's not mine but i know the IP Adress.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would do any other request...

```
$.get("myFile.php", function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

Comment: With the addition of setting up your permissions to allow such a request.